# How to show the code hierarchy at the top of Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio-3.1

Android Studio used to show the hierarchy before I upgraded to Android 3.1 a few days ago.

If you placed the cursor in method foo(), the top would show something like
MyClass > foo()

Is there a way to restore this witih AS 3.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Studio 3.1:
Settings -> Editor -> General -> Breadcrumbs.
You can set it on top and on the bottom of IDE.

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you so much for the answer.  I have just realized the information was at the bottom, and I never noticed it because I was used to seeing it at the top.  I missed it badly.